# TypeError with Chrome API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, typescript-typings, chrome-app-developer-tool

I've got a react project going that injects itself into a chrome extension through the content script. I've installed the @types/chrome and in my app.tsx I've included

```
/// <reference types="chrome">
```

and tried `/* global chrome */` as well. However, I continue to get TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined.

In my app.tsx, i've got a call to the api :

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active:true,  currentWindow:true}, (tabs:chrome chrome.tabs.Tab[]) => { ....
```

Judging from this tutorial: 
https://blog.usejournal.com/making-an-interactive-chrome-extension-with-react-524483d7aa5d
I think i'm on the right track. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use chrome.tabs in a content script. Can't do that. Only an extension page script like the popup script or background script can do it. If you insert an iframe pointing to an extension html file into the web page, the iframe script will be able to use chrome.tabs.

Comment: Here's a different and arguably [better tutorial](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39).